# C++ logic error

Tags: c++

I got 158, 1000, and 140 for the money outputs while I played. 
The original amount I put in was 100. 
The total amount of money and the amount of money entered by the user aren't showing up correctly when ran.
Sometimes, the total and the amount entered displays correctly, it should be noted. 
But not always, and that's a problem.
There is some logic error(s) I can't figure out. Help?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

void switchStatementsCalculations (int &slot1, int &slot2, int &slot3, string cherries, string
                                   oranges, string plums, string bells, string melons, string bars);

void calculateAmountEarnedByPlaying (double &money, int slot1, int slot2, int slot3,
                                     double &total);

int main()
{
    int slot1;
    int slot2;
    int slot3;

    double money=0;
    double total=0;
    double amountOfMoneyEnterd=0;
    int count;

    string cherries = "cherries";
    string oranges = "oranges";
    string plums = "plums";
    string bells = "bells";
    string melons = "melons";
    string bars = "bars";
    string doAgain;

    cout << "We are going to be playing a slot machine game today." << endl;
    srand(time(0));

    do
    {

        cout << "Please enter the amount of money you'd like to insert into the slot machine. We will pull the lever for you." << endl;
        cin >> money;
        cout << "You put in $" << money << endl;




        slot1=rand()%6+1;
        slot2=rand()%6+1;
        slot3=rand()%6+1;

        switchStatementsCalculations(slot1, slot2, slot3, cherries, oranges, plums, bells, melons, bars);

        calculateAmountEarnedByPlaying(money, slot1, slot2, slot3, total);

        amountOfMoneyEnterd=(amountOfMoneyEnterd+money);





        cout << "Would you like to play again? Please type yes if so." << endl;
        cin >> doAgain;
        if(doAgain!= "yes")
        {
            cout << "The total amount of money you put in the slot machine is " << amountOfMoneyEnterd << endl;
            cout << "The total amount of money you won is $" << total << endl;
        }

    }
    while(doAgain=="yes");


    system("Pause");
    return 0;
}

void switchStatementsCalculations(int &slot1, int &slot2, int &slot3, string cherries, string
                                  oranges, string plums, string bells, string melons, string bars)
{
    switch (slot1)
    {
    case 1:
        cout << "You got " << cherries << endl;
    case 2:
        cout << "You got " << oranges << endl;
        break;
    case 3:
        cout << "You got " << plums << endl;
        break;
    case 4:
        cout << "You got " << bells << endl;
        break;
    case 5:
        cout << "You got " << melons << endl;
        break;
    case 6:
        cout << "You got " << bars << endl;
    }

    switch (slot2)
    {
    case 1:
        cout << "You got " << cherries << endl;
        break;
    case 2:
        cout << "You got " << oranges << endl;
        break;
    case 3:
        cout << "You got " << plums << endl;
        break;
    case 4:
        cout << "You got " << bells << endl;
        break;
    case 5:
        cout << "You got " << melons << endl;
        break;
    case 6:
        cout << "You got " << bars << endl;

    }

    switch (slot3)
    {
    case 1:
        cout << "You got " << cherries << endl;
        break;
    case 2:
        cout << "You got " << oranges << endl;
        break;
    case 3:
        cout << "You got " << plums << endl;
        break;
    case 4:
        cout << "You got " << bells << endl;
        break;
    case 5:
        cout << "You got " << melons << endl;
        break;
    case 6:
        cout << "You got " << bars << endl;

    }
}

void calculateAmountEarnedByPlaying(double &money, int slot1, int slot2, int slot3, double &total)

{
    double won=0;

    if(slot1==slot2 || slot1==slot3 || slot2==slot3)
    {
        cout << "Congratulations! You won." << endl;
        won=(money * 2);
        cout << "You won " << won << endl;
    }


    else if ((slot1==slot2 && slot1==slot3) || (slot2==slot1 && slot2==slot3) || (slot3==slot1 && slot3==slot2))
    {
        cout << "Congratulations! You won." << endl;
        won=(money*3);
        cout << "You won " << won << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "You didn't earn any money." << endl;
    }

    total=(total+won);
}
```

Comment: You should try stepping through the code with a debugger.

Comment: I used an online one, but it gave me no results. I assumed I didn't have one until I manually added everything up myself.

Comment: `srand(time(0));`  This should only be done once outside and before your loop, and not repeatedly done in the loop.  Also, now is a good time to learn arrays, as you have the same code repeated 6 times over.

Comment: I unfortunately don't have much time right now. However, we will be learning that in the next chapter. 

So, that should go do and at the bottom after return 0; }?

Will this fix my logic error of giving me the wrong values in the total variable and the amountEarned variable?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie
Sorry, I forgot to tag you, haha.

Comment: @Kikuo You should seed the random number generator only once in your program.  Obviously that has to go before the loop.  Instead you're seeding it every single time the loop is executed.  As to fixing the error, you never told us what the exact set of input values you used and the output to be expected.  Also, it isn't a good idea to randomize stuff when your program doesn't work.  First get your program to work with known values before you randomly select slots.  Adding random values makes the problem harder to solve, since you never will have the same set of inputs to work with.

Comment: It has to be randomized to work, in my opinion. I'm only a noob, so I may be wrong, but it adds up random values. 

When I ran the program, the amount of money I earned from gambling was 158, 1000, and 140. 

The amount of money I put in the machine, however, was a hundred. Hopefully that helps. I'll fix the random generator right now. 

@PaulMcKenzie

Comment: @Kikuo - No.  Randomization happens *after* you know how to add up known, predictable values.  How about identifying what the random values are that produce the error(s)?  Once you know what they are, you *hard-code those values in your program and fix the errors*.  Once you fix the errors with known values, **then** you add randomization.  Trying to fix basic errors, and the data is bouncing back and forth between runs is not an ideal way to go about this.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/bowykb
http://prntscr.com/bowynv

Here are the screenshots. See how the totals of the money put in the slot machine and the money earned from it is wrong? 

The money from the slot machine is correct, but it isn't always, and the money entered is also wrong.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie sounds good. Mind hinting what's wrong? I'm completely lost to what would be causing it.

Comment: Did you turn up the warnings in your compiler to full?  Please see the answer.

Comment: Sure did. 

Says everythings good. 
@PaulMcKenzie

Comment: If it's Visual Studio, set the warning level to `W4`.  If it's gcc, make sure that the warnings are set higher than what they're set for now.

Comment: [See here for Visual C++](http://rextester.com/WERAG86743) -- Note the warnings.

Comment: [See here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a04d1b1102f1834a) for g++.  Again, look at the warnings.

Answer (score 0):

One mistake is this in your `calculateAmountEarnedByPlaying` function:

`double won;`

You did not initialize this variable, thus it contains an indeterminate value.

It is only set if you've won something, but not set if you didn't win.  You then do this at the end of your function:

`total = (total + won);`

If `won` is not initialized, then `total` will also be set to an indeterminate value (or undefined behavior occurs).

The `won` variable should be initialized to `0`:

`double won = 0;`

Most compilers give a warning if you access an uninitialized variable like this.  Please check that you have your warnings on to detect these issues.

---

The other issue is that you forgot a `break` in your switch statements:

```
switch (slot1)
{    
    case 1:
        cout << "You got " << cherries << endl;  // no break statement
    case 2:
        cout << "You got " << oranges << endl;
    break;
```

If `slot1` is `1`, it will print both sets of output for case 1 and case 2.

None of this would be necessary if you used arrays instead of 6 separate variables and 6 separate lines of output:

```
   std::string slot_items[] = {"cherries", "oranges", "plums", "bells", "melons", "bars"};
   //...
   int slots[3];
   //...
   for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
      slots[i] = rand()%6+1;
   //...
   // inside the function...
   //...
   for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
      cout << "You got " << slot_items[slots[i]] << endl;
```

A two line `for` loop replaces 60 lines of `switch` and case statements.

Comment: Well, I think that fixed my issue. I'll edit and show my edited code. Thanks! 

Leave any comments if you see anything else!

Comment: I had one more question. Do you see how the it first shows four fruit the first time I insert money and then shows two fruit when I insert money the second times? I feel like this is a mistake in my code. Shouldn't it only be showing three fruit each time I put in money since there are only three slot machines? http://prntscr.com/bp9okf

@PaulMcKenzie

Comment: Look at your first set of `switch` statements -- you forgot a `break` statement for case 1.